# Select a variable at compile-time

Tags: c++, templates

I'd like to be able to specify via a boolean which of two variables I need to use at compile time, all of this **without direct SFINAE**. Just one single function, similar to `std::conditional` but not returning types.

So for instance in a class `test`, I'd like to have

```
class test
{
    template <class T, bool first, MAGIC_HAPPENS var>
    void apply_it(T &t)
    {
        for (auto &p : var) p.apply(t);
    }

    std::vector<myfunction> var1;
    std::vector<myfunction> var2;
}
```

The use is simple: if I specify `first == true` then it should apply the loop with `var == var1`, otherwise `var == var2`.

Is it possible?

Comment: couldnt you pass both var1 and var2 to the function with the bool? Then use the bool to determine which to loop to run?

Comment: simply provide a specialization for `first==false` that uses `var2`, no need for sfinae

Comment: if you're using C++17, then `if constexpr` might be an option here

Comment: @tobi303 right now I am doing this, I'd like to avoid double coding.

Comment: what do you mean with double coding? you cannot avoid to write some code to select one or the other somewhere

Comment: @hellyale yes, but I don't want any runtime `if`s.

Comment: Until you explain why `apply(some_bool ? var1 : var2)` (or some variant with `constexpr if`) is not a proper solution, I could not help.

Comment: if you mean that the real mehtod has more code that you dont want to duplicate then write a wrapper method that does only the selection (based on bool template parameter) and passes a reference to the vector you want to the actual implementation... or something like that....

Comment: There is not a real-world need of course, I want to learn more about TMP, that is why I am asking this question: it is easy, but tricky if templated without specializations.

Comment: @senseiwa, there are much better exercises to learn TMP.

Comment: i have the feeling that you simplified you problem too much to get a mcve, because in the code you show here it isnt clear why sfinae would be required, it is almost too trivial....

Comment: I am aware of that, but this is what I am doing as an exercise, even if it seems silly :)

Comment: @tobi303 nothing more than that, I swear, easy and simple. My objective is to make some magic inside the template definition similar to `std::conditional`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for fun(*), a *minimal* C++17(**) modification to your current code snippet might be

```
class test
{
    std::vector<myfunction> var1;
    std::vector<myfunction> var2;

    template <class T, bool first, std::vector<myfunction> test::*var = first ? &test::var1 : &test::var2 >
    void apply_it(T &t)
    {
        for (auto &p : this->*var) p.apply(t);
    }
};
```

---

(*) I see no situation in which such a thing would be preferable over the other suggested solutions ...

(**) as far as I know, this requires C++17 due to linkage requirement of template non type pointer parameters ...

Comment: I don't think it requires C++17, as pointer to members works as long as they are refereed directly, just like in your case. For example, you could not have a constexpr pointer to member variable and put it in template parameters before C++17.

Comment: @guillaumeracicot I'm not sure I follow you ... in the above, I was referring exactly to the use of those pointer to members in the template non type parameters (just because the OP wanted it there, for some mysterious reason).

Comment: Yes! And I just comfirmed to you that you indeed don't need c++17 for for solution ;) You are referring to the members directly in your non-type template parameters.

If you weren't referring to the members directly (let's say through a constexpr variable) then you would have require C++17

Answer (score 4):

For C++17 and above:

```
class test
{
    template <class T, bool first>
    void apply_it(T &t)
    {
        if constexpr (first)
        {
            for (auto &p : var1) p.apply(t);
        }
        else
        {
            for (auto &p : var2) p.apply(t);
        }
    }

    std::vector<myfunction> var1;
    std::vector<myfunction> var2;
}
```

`if constexpr` is evaluated at compile time if the condition is constexpr, which is the case for template parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in C++11 with a pointer to data member:

```
class test
{
    template <class T, bool first>
    void apply_it(T &t)
    {
        constexpr auto var = first ? &test::var1 : &test::var2;
        for (auto &p : this->*var) p.apply(t);
    }

    std::vector<myfunction> var1;
    std::vector<myfunction> var2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template<std::size_t I, class...Args>
decltype(auto) pick( Args&&... args ) {
  return std::get<I>( std::forward_as_tuple( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) );
}
```

`pick` selects at compile time something from a list.

```
class test
{
  template <bool first, class T>
  void apply_it(T&& t)
  {
    auto&& var = pick<first?0:1>(var1, var2);
    for (auto&& p : var)
      p.apply(t);
  }

  std::vector<myfunction> var1;
  std::vector<myfunction> var2;
};
```

I also made some minor improvements while I was copy pasting.